# Dropbox SDK bug

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, dropbox, nsurlsession

I was found something strange when I using Dropbox SDK 1.3.14

And here is how the bug happen , I put a dictionary tree like

/Comic/Author - Comic name (ex.浦澤直樹 - Monster)/Volume1/0.jpg , 1.jpg , ...)

And I want download the jpg to iOS app,And also create the same dictionary tree as Dropbox

So I create a dictionary tree in Document , It looks like

/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/12711FE6...290C7EAF50/Documents/Dropbox/Comic/浦澤直樹 - Monster/Volume1

Than I try to download the first page of comic

But it shows an error tell me the dictionary is not exist .

I use NSFileManager to check , It did exist .

Finally I find the problem

At this callback

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata {
    for (DBMetadata *file in metadata.contents) {
      NSLog(@"File Path : %@",file.path);  
    }
}
```

Path will print like this

1./Comic

2./Comic/浦澤直樹 - Monster

3./Comic/浦澤直樹 - Monster/Volume1

4./Comic/浦澤直樹 - **monster**/Volume1/0.jpg

Now at the last file path , it gives me a different path name

I don't know why , but if I use this path to check is the parent dictionary is ready , It will return false.

So I never can download the file to specified path success

I was wonder does anyone got same issue like me ?

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox itself is case-insensitive, with attempts to be case-preserving. However, due to various specifics, the API can't always return the expected case for every path component. So, for any file or folder metadata, the filename/last path component should have the preserved case, but other path components are not guaranteed to.

We realize this is non-ideal of course and are looking into ways to improve it, but I don't have a solution to offer right now.

If you need the preserved casing, you'll need to build it up from the last component in each parent entry.

Comment: Now I use some workaround way to fix this problem , I build a case-sensitive path table to match the file path .